# Matching two sets of columns and creating a third column with blank rows if it doesn't match

Tags: excel

This is original excel worksheet that I have.

[image]

I need to match these two columns and get the output as follows.

[image]

i.e., if there is a match between any two rows then create a new row, else
create blank cells wherever it doesn't match.

Is it actually possible to do in MS-excel? I really hope it is possible, because the worksheet contains ~900 rows and I do not wish to do it manually.

Help me solving this.

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$35,0)),"",A2)

I am using the above formula. It does work for matching list 1 with that of list 2 but not the other way round.
How do I use it to combine both the ways?

Comment: Have you worked with VBA already? Would an VBA-Script solve your questions?

Comment: @JulianG No. I haven't worked with VBA. If VBA-Script provides me a solution, then I am very much willing to use it.

Comment: Have you done any research on your own yet? Thought about any way to implement this?

Comment: First, we should translate your requirement in a more technical way. You want to compare the entries in one row and move the entire block of entries one row to the bottom. You want to repeat this, until one of the rows is empty.

Comment: @JulianG I've edited my question with the formula that I am using. Googled and found that formula

Answer (score 1):

It appears based on the limited example you gave, that your pattern is as follows:

1. Process Col B value if no match
2. Process all matching Col A and Col B values until no match
3. Process all unmatched Col A values until Col A and Col B values match

Since this sounds like a one off project, I have included some VBA to accomplish this, but it is not pretty. Below are some screenshots to walk you through it.

1. To access the VBA Editor, Press Alt+F11
   [image]
2. Right click on one of the objects in the left pane and select Insert / Module
   [image]
3. A module will be created and a blank pane will appear on the right
   [image]
4. Copy and paste the below vba code in the blank pane on the right under General

   ```
    Public Sub SortAndDisplayData()
    Const sColA As String = "A"
    Const sColB As String = "B"
    Const sColC As String = "C"
    Const sColD As String = "D"
    Dim oColADict As Object, oColBDict As Object
    Dim lRow As Long, lBegRow As Long, lEndRow As Long, lIndex As Long
    Dim vData As Variant, vKey As Variant, vColAKeys As Variant
    Dim vColAKey As Variant, vColBKeys As Variant, vColBKey As Variant

        Set oColADict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        oColADict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Set oColBDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        oColBDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

        With ActiveSheet
            ' Get last row, max of Col A / Col B.
            lEndRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max( _
            .Cells(Application.Rows.Count, sColA).End(xlUp).Row, _
            .Cells(Application.Rows.Count, sColB).End(xlUp).Row)

            ' Column A.
            lEndRow = .Cells(Application.Rows.Count, sColA).End(xlUp).Row
            vData = .Range(.Cells(2, sColA), .Cells(lEndRow, sColA)).Value
            vData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vData)
            For lIndex = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
                Call oColADict.Add(vData(lIndex), Nothing)
            Next

            ' Column B.
            lEndRow = .Cells(Application.Rows.Count, sColB).End(xlUp).Row
            vData = .Range(.Cells(2, sColB), .Cells(lEndRow, sColB)).Value
            vData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vData)
            For lIndex = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
                Call oColBDict.Add(vData(lIndex), Nothing)
            Next

            ' Recreate in Col C and Col D.
            lRow = 1
            Call .Columns(sColC & ":" & sColD).Delete(shift:=xlToLeft)
            .Cells(lRow, sColC).Value = "List 1"
            .Cells(lRow, sColD).Value = "List 2"
            vColAKeys = oColADict.keys
            vColBKeys = oColBDict.keys
            For Each vColBKey In vColBKeys
                lRow = lRow + 1
                If oColADict.exists(vColBKey) And oColBDict.exists(vColBKey) Then
                    .Cells(lRow, sColC).Value = vColBKey
                    .Cells(lRow, sColD).Value = vColBKey

                    lIndex = GetNextIndex(vColAKeys, vColBKey)
                    vKey = vColAKeys(lIndex)
                    Do While oColADict.exists(vKey) And oColBDict.exists(vKey)
                        lRow = lRow + 1
                        .Cells(lRow, sColC).Value = vKey
                        .Cells(lRow, sColD).Value = vKey

                        Call oColBDict.Remove(vKey)
                        lIndex = lIndex + 1
                        vKey = vColAKeys(lIndex)
                    Loop
                ElseIf oColBDict.exists(vColBKey) Then
                    .Cells(lRow, sColD).Value = vColBKey
                ElseIf oColADict.exists(vKey) Then
                    .Cells(lRow, sColC).Value = vKey
                    If lIndex < UBound(vColAKeys) Then
                        lIndex = lIndex + 1
                        vKey = vColAKeys(lIndex)
                    End If
                    Do While ((oColADict.exists(vKey)) And (Not oColBDict.exists(vKey)) And (lIndex < UBound(vColAKeys)))
                        lRow = lRow + 1
                        .Cells(lRow, sColC).Value = vKey
                        lIndex = lIndex + 1
                        vKey = vColAKeys(lIndex)
                    Loop
                End If
            Next

            Do While oColADict.exists(vKey)
                lRow = lRow + 1
                .Cells(lRow, sColC).Value = vKey
                If lIndex < UBound(vColAKeys) Then
                    lIndex = lIndex + 1
                    vKey = vColAKeys(lIndex)
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop

            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With

        Call MsgBox("Finished")
        Set oColADict = Nothing: Set oColBDict = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Function GetNextIndex(vKeys As Variant, vKey As Variant) As Long
    Dim lIndex As Long
        For lIndex = LBound(vKeys) To UBound(vKeys)
            If vKeys(lIndex) = vKey Then
                lIndex = lIndex + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        GetNextIndex = lIndex
    End Function
   ```
5. Click in the SortAndDisplayData Sub
6. Click Run in the Menu
   [image]
7. Click File and Close to return to Excel
   [image]

The data was created in Col C and Col D so that you can compare and tweak it if it isn't quite right. I apologize for the complexity since you do not know VBA.